# Is it a legal requirement to put your VAT number on a receipt?

Tags: united-kingdom, vat, receipt

Someone recently complained to our business that our receipts didn't have our VAT number on them.

If anyone ever requests a VAT receipt/invoice then we draw one up manually, otherwise, we just issue normal receipts for the products in our cafe.

Is there any legal requirement to have our VAT number on the general product receipts that we issue to our customers?

Comment: I question whether this is on-topic for **Personal** Finance & Money.

Comment: Any suggestions on where's best for it?

Comment: I'm not sure.  Your company must have a bookkeeper or Chartered Accountant.

Comment: Absolutely 100% legally required. As a VAT registered company, you MUST give a receipt including VAT for every money that you receive. And VAT numbers must be consecutive.

Comment: Thanks @gnasher729, when you say consecutive do you mean the VAT number should change per receipt? I thought it was one VAT number for a company?

Comment: The VAT number only needs to be included on an **invoice**. Receipts aren't even legally required to be provided, but are obviously common. I couldn't find anything on the gov.uk website about receipt requirements (possibly there aren't any) but Tesco groceries and Argos, for example, require you to request a VAT receipt specifically.

Comment: I think talking about invoices is unrelated as @EliNathan mentioned receipts, but it is the case that the **invoice** number would increment for each one, but the **VAT** number would remain the same.

Comment: So long as the receipt isn't purporting to be an invoice - and is simply a ticket of acknowledgement which displays the items purchased and the cash paid - then there is no requirement for it to say anything in particular regarding VAT. However, you must comply with other rules, such as providing VAT receipts to those who identify themselves as VAT registered. In a retail establishment serving the public, it is the customer who must identify themselves as such and ask for a VAT receipt.

Comment: @gnasher729, that does not apply to members of the "VAT retail schemes", where the VAT can be accounted for purely by taking gross amounts off the till roll (although records of the individual transactions, the items therein, and any adjustments or reversals, must be created and retained). Only VAT invoices need to be numbered consecutively, the numbering does not take account of uninvoiced transactions, and these invoices must be requested by the customer. The 'ordinary' till receipts given to customers need not be numbered, nor in any other way compliant with the rules on VAT invoices.

Comment: Thank you @Steve, you're right, we're not talking about invoices, just receipts. If a VAT receipt is requested then we can make one up at any time. We're also going to start adding our VAT number to receipts even though it doesn't look like there's any legal requirement as it seems to just be helpful for people claiming expenses.